# linux find command issue

Tags: linux, bash, find

I have a shell script which was written for Mac OSX and now ported to a linux machine. I don't have access to a linux machine currently( I will be setting up a virtual machine soon)
Some statements in the shell script are failing, which is expected.
I have a find command statement used for finding files sizes greater than 1MB:

```
oversize=`find "$somePath" -maxdepth 1 -size +1048576c -iname "*.gz" -print0 | xargs -0 ls -l | wc -l`    
oversize=$((oversize * 1))
if [ $oversize -eq 0 ];then
  echo "OK"
else  
  echo "Limit exceeded"

fi
```

Any idea if something is wrong with this statement ? It flagged a file whose size was 1045400 bytes

Answer (score 1):

**I have a find command statement used for finding files sizes greater than 1MB:**

For that use `-size +1M`

```
oversize=`find -maxdepth 2 -size +1M -exec ls -lh {} \; | wc -l`
oversize=$((oversize * 1))
echo size of oversize = $oversize
if [ $oversize -eq 0 ];then
  echo "OK"
else  
  echo "Limit exceeded"

fi
```

It 's giving the output

> size of oversize = 96
>
> Limit exceeded

That is true right?

**update**

See here for me its giving correct output

```
[max@localhost ~]$ find Downloads/ -maxdepth 1 -size +1048576c -name "*.pdf" -print0 | xargs -0 ls -l | wc -l
9
[max@localhost ~]$ find Downloads/ -maxdepth 1 -size +1048576c -name "*.pdf" -print0 | xargs -0 ls -l
-rw-rw-r-- 1 max max  1443224 Oct 11 17:04 Downloads/------.pdf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 max max  1330293 Sep 29 15:27 Downloads/-------.pdf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 max max 12825921 Oct  1 18:49 Downloads/--------.pdf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 max max  8197602 Sep 29 15:46 Downloads/--------.pdf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 max max  1604859 Oct 11 17:23 Downloads/------.pdf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 max max  2792931 Oct 24 11:27 Downloads/--------.pdf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 max max  5382152 Oct  9 14:52 Downloads/----------.pdf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 max max  1113609 Sep 29 15:46 Downloads/--------.pdf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 max max  9198710 Sep 29 15:40 Downloads/---------.pdf
```

Comment: I used your command and the script stared giving correct output. What's wrong with my implementation?

Comment: `$somepath` what path you are giving here? And what error you are getting?